# How to mention link extractor rules when using BaseSpider in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

Suppose this is my code

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

from dmoz.items import DmozItem

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
   domain_name = "dmoz.org"
   start_urls = [
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/",
       "http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Resources/"
   ]

   def parse(self, response):
       hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
       sites = hxs.select('//ul[2]/li')
       items = []
       for site in sites:
           item = DmozItem()
           item['title'] = site.select('a/text()').extract()
           item['link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()
           item['desc'] = site.select('text()').extract()
           items.append(item)
       return items

SPIDER = DmozSpider()
```

If i have used crawlSpider then i could uses Rules to implement thelink extractor but how can i mention rules in base spider. Like in above example. Because rules is only avaialble in crawlspider not base spider

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could parse the response for your rule criteria and then pass the successful responses on to a second callback? Pseudo-code below:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # check response for rule criteria
    ...
    if rule: 
        # create new request to pass to second callback
        req = Request("http://www.example.com/follow", callback=self.parse2)
        return req

def parse2(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    # do stuff with the successful response
```

Comment: can i call parse function recursively. or it will be bteer to have second parse function

Comment: The `parse` function is going to get called for all of your start urls. It would be up to you to correctly work through each of the responses and find links that match your rule(s) before passing each new request to `parse2`